# Delete some elements from List inside a List at Python

Tags: python, list

The list:

```
L=[('true','500'),('false','600'),('true','6500'),('true','4567')]
```

I want to delete the `True` and `False` elements, so I have the list `L` like:

```
L=['500','600','6500','4567']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `True` and `False` are always the first elements in the items of `L` you can do this:

```
mylist = [item[1] for item in L]
```

Comment: And what if true and false are always the second elements in the terms of L ?

Comment: Create `mylist = [item[0] for item in L]` assuming the items you are looking for are the first elements in L.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this

```
>>> [i[1] for i in L]
['500','600','6500','4567']
```

Comment: And what if true and false are always the second elements in the terms of L ?